# Delete multiple files older then 30 days batch script with wildcard

Tags: batch-file, wildcard

i would like to know how you can delete multiple files in different folders with batch commands.

I have the following code, this code works fine for 1 map but i need to do it for multiple maps : 
`forfiles /p "D:\CHILI_Publisher\Data\Environments\Adecco\Cache_Data\Assets" /s /d -10 /c "cmd /c echo @file"
PAUSE`

This is the code for the various maps and various file types with wildcards (this one gives an error : The directory name is invalid:
 `forfiles /p "D:\CHILI_Publisher\Data\Environments\*.*\Cache_Data\*.*" /s /d -10 /c "cmd /c echo @file"
PAUSE`

Tl;DR : I have an error and would like to know how to use a wildcard correctly in batch files.

Comment: why *. and not only *

Comment: I edited my code - with just a * it still gives a error. @amitdayama

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap `FORFILES` in a `FOR` loop:

```
for /d %D in (c:\temp\a*;c:\temp\b*;c:\temp\c*) do forfiles /p %D /s /c "cmd /c echo @file" /d -10
```

If you need to find all folders named `CACHE_DATA` under a super folder you can navigate to the super folder (`cd D:\CHILI_Publisher\Data\Environments`) and run this:

```
for /f %F in ('dir /B /S /AD cache_data') do for /d %D in (%F) do forfiles /p %D /s /c "cmd /c echo @file" /d -10
```

If you put the script in a `BATCH` file remember to escape `%` with `%%`.

Comment: K thanks , but do you have to repeat every path (put all paths in loop). Or is there a way to define 1 path? The main problem here is that you need to access all files in a path and continue after this (wildcard) folder and continue to the next folder .. The structure of these folders are all the same though ..